# Eliminate few fields from Copy Paste functionality on Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I want to eliminate few fields from copying on Sales Order screen so that when I copy an Order to create similar order by pasting, these field do not get copied over or it gets to default.

I tried with PXCopyPasteHiddenFields attribute but that did not helped me and throwing an error.

[image]

And then when I try to save the Order, I get below error-

[image]

Here is the code I tried in Sales Order extension class-

```html
[PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(SOOrder.cancelled), typeof(SOOrder.preAuthTranNumber), typeof(SOOrder.ownerID), typeof(SOOrder.workgroupID), 
      typeof(SOOrder.paymentMethodID), typeof(SOOrder.pMInstanceID), typeof(SOOrder.cashAccountID))]
    public PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>> CurrentDocument;
```

I have added `PaymentMethodID`, `PMInstanceID` and `CashAccountID` fields more to existing CurrentDocument DAC which I want to eliminate from copying when I copy Order. These fields are from Payment Settings tab on Sales Order screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I failed to reproduce the unknown error you say it's throwing. It also seem to be working, cash account id is not copied, it's just getting initialized after providing  Customer field which initialize Payment Method which in turns initialize Cash Account.

Comment: I have update the question with the error I am getting. The goal here is probably I just create new order by copying and save it directly without any error. That could be Payment Method and Cash Account defaulted.

Comment: At that point I would recommend to unpublish all customizations and make a new single one with a SOOrderEntry extension that does contain only the code in your question. See if you can reproduce the error in that context. If so then it might be a configuration issue, at that point I would try on a new instance populated with Demo data from Acumatica wizard. So far it appear doubtful that PXCopyPasteHiddenFields alone leads to those errors.

Comment: Other possibility is that these are not technical error, aren't there any error indicator on screen to tell the user left GroundCollect required field blank? Also if you prevent copying PaymentMethod then it might initialize to it's default value and still copy related field like CCProcessingCenterID which is then invalid with the initialized PaymentMethod. In other words, if you disable Payment Method copying you should disable copying of all related fields in the Payment Settings tab otherwise you just copy corrupted fields in there.

Comment: Try this, create a new sales order, fill in only Customer and Location. Save and Copy it and Paste it. I wouldn't expect any error in that scenario. Imagine this other scenario, Customer payment method initialize to Cash but you change it to Credit Card payment method and fill in Credit Card Number. Since you prevent copy of payment method, it will not copy Credit Card payment method but instead re-initialize to Cash for that customer. But you're still copying Credit Card number and for a Cash Payment this is invalid. I think your errors happens because of something similar.

Comment: Ok, I will try that